# How to hide menu items in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'm using Qt Quick Controls 2 and write this code for context menu:

```
Menu{
    id: contextmenu
    x: ( parent.width - contextmenu.width ) / 2
    y: ( parent.height - contextmenu.height ) / 2
    modal: true

    property int selid

    MenuItem {
        text: "Compare"
        visible: isexp
    }
    Divider{ visible: isexp }
    MenuItem {
        text: "Send..."
        visible: isexp
    }
    Divider{ visible: isexp }
    MenuItem {
        text: "Edit..."
    }
    Divider{}
    MenuItem {
        text: "Delete"
    }
}
```

Divider - it is my component. **isexp** is is property of object. When **isexp** false menu is shows wrong. See screenshot:
https://s31.postimg.org/c608kdtbv/qqq.png

How to change visibility of menu items and show menu properly. Thank for advice.

Answer (score 7):

Setting the `height` to `0` in addition to hiding the items works:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property bool itemsVisible: true

    Menu {
        id: contextmenu
        x: (parent.width - contextmenu.width) / 2
        y: (parent.height - contextmenu.height) / 2
        modal: true

        MenuItem {
            text: "Compare"
            visible: itemsVisible
            height: visible ? implicitHeight : 0
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Send..."
            visible: itemsVisible
            height: visible ? implicitHeight : 0
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Edit..."
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Delete"
        }
    }

    Button {
        text: "Open"
        onClicked: {
            itemsVisible = !itemsVisible
            contextmenu.open()
        }
    }
}
```

This is because the height of the menu is based off the `contentHeight` of the internal `ListView`.

Comment: Disabled item is still visible. I need to modify menu.

Comment: I know, that's why I said I don't think it's a supported use case. Actually, perhaps if you set the height to 0 as well..

Comment: I've found that it's better to use `enabled` and `height` in combination instead of `visible`. This is because while the latter obviously does visually hide the item, it doesn't prevent keyboard interaction, so an invisible, zero height `MenuItem` can still be selected and triggered using the arrow keys and enter.

Answer (score -1):

I found workaround but it is not so good:

```
Menu{
    id: contextmenu
    x: ( parent.width - contextmenu.width ) / 2
    y: ( parent.height - contextmenu.height ) / 2
    modal: true

    MenuItem {
        text: "Compare"
    }
    Divider{ }
    MenuItem {
        text: "Send..."
    }
    Divider{ }

    MenuItem {
        text: "Edit..."
    }
    Divider{}
    MenuItem {
        text: "Delete"
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        if( !isexp )
        {
            contextmenu.removeItem(0)
            contextmenu.removeItem(0)
            contextmenu.removeItem(0)
            contextmenu.removeItem(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In early Qt quick version, like Controls 1.4, you can use the private method of  the menu object: `__closeAndDestroy()`.

*But there is no guarantee for this private method.*